# Windows DNS & DHCP / Ubuntu Web Server

Tags: windows

I want to set up my Windows Server to serve DNS and DHCP, in the MS world that is not a problem as long as I only have to think about Windows OS machines.  But I have Ubuntu Server running LAMP i.e my web server and I want Windows DNS to take care of the CNAME records for web Alias addresses etc.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: The Windows DNS server role is RFC compliant.

Answer (score 2):

A DNS server running on Windows have to be managed like any other DNS server running on any other operating systems.

You are confusing the concept of dynamic DNS through DHCP with regular static DNS records. They do not relate.

Add your CNAME/A-records like you would on any other DNS server.